# UINavigationItem.title.frame = 0 0 width height?

Tags: ios

[image]why is this? I do not understand. Isn't it in the middle of the UInavigationitem?
the origin of the title view could not be 0 0, right? should be something greater than 0 0.

But when I printed it on console, that is it...
even though it does have the autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean UINavigationItem.titleView.frame, since the title property is a String, not a view.

An origin of 0, 0 would be expected if the titleView was a subview of another view. If you use Xcode's nifty Debug View Hierarchy feature, you'll see that that is the case. It's a subview of a UINavigationItemView object.

Take a look at UINavigationItem.titleView.superview.frame instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes it is titleView instead of title. I did engage the view debugger to check out the size. Also logged on console:UINavigationItem.titleView.superview.frame = {{0, 20}, {320, 44}} If one notices that x=0 still, this is what bothers me. if the title view is in the center of the navigationItem for this view, x should be greater than 0, somewhere around 100. Right?I updated a screen shot. Is position the origin on size inspector? What is anchor position?